# Render QT GUI into SFML window?

Tags: qt, sfml

I just want to render QT widgets into a SFML window without using the QT implementation of opengl. Is this possible and how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: 
It's either impossible or not worth the effort.

The long one:
The only way to render a QWidget derived widget is to draw it on another QWidget. If you don't write some ultra-hackish QT-SFML glue-code, that won't be possible. And even if you do that, you still need to use qmake in the compilation process.

**edit, nearly one year later:**
That's not actually [that hackish](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-qt.php)... We both should had used Google.